# Why is there a 'Pods' project separate from my regular project in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-project, xcode-workspace, xcodeproj

**Scenario:**

When I open the iOS folder for my project `InTow` in Xcode, I see two separate projects in the Navigator Area: `InTow` and `Pods`.

[image]

As well, when I search recursively within the `ios/` folder, there are only two `.xcodeproj` files: `InTow.xcodeproj` and `Pods.xcodeproj`, and only one `.xcworkspace` file: `InTow.xcworkspace`.

**My Question is:**

When I click to open the `ios/` folder in Xcode, which of the following does it do?

1) Look for the first `.xcworkspace` file it finds, and open that? If so, is the reason the `InTow` and `Pods` projects get open in Xcode that those are the two projects referenced in `InTow.xcworkspace`? Does an `ios/` folder always contain only one `.xcworkspace` file?

2) Look for any and all `.xcodeproj` files, and open the corresponding projects?

3) Something else?

Answer (score 0):

The `Pods` directory is just where all the pods files are located, if you are using CocoaPods to handle your libraries, the command `pod install` does this for you, once you run that command, you should only open the .xcworkspace file and not the .xcodeproj, otherwise you’ll encounter build errors.